# Export repeater data to pdf in C#.Net

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, repeater

Can anybody help me how to export *Repeater* data to PDF file **without** using iTextSharp.
I am generating PDF files from *Repeater* control using iTextSharp, it works properly but are there any other suggestions on how to export repeater data to a PDF document?

Comment: If you don't want to use iTextSharp I think you will have to write your own library.

Comment: there is no other library?

Comment: what's wrong with iTextSharp?

Comment: Of course there are other libraries, too, e.g. PDFBox, PDF Clown, etc. But what improvements are you actually looking for? Depending on that, others might tell whether any of those is a better choice for you.

Answer (score 1):

use the below code.Hope it will resolve your issue.

```
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using System.Text;

protected void BtnExportToPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        Repeater1.DataBind(); 
        Repeater1.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f,10f,10f,0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,but you also use itextsharp.dll

Comment: worked for me but after removing Repeater1.DataBind();